# How to deal with different API levels in code

Tags: android, material-design, android-compatibility, android-api-levels

I started with development with material design.

My layouts and styles are separated in those for pre-lollipop devices and those for lollipop and higher.

E.g i use

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
style="@style/Toolbar" />
```

In my pre-lollipop layout file and

```
<Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
style="@style/Toolbar" />
```

in the other one.
Therefore I am forced to use two different objects in the related activity class. That confuses me a lot and leads to confusing code.

I know how to distinguish between API levels via

```
Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
```

Nevertheless what is the best approach to solve this problem?

Thank you for answers

Comment: don't mix it like this. Use the one from `support` for as long as your minApi is smaller than 21

Comment: Actually I wanted to avoid the use of another library but indeed it seems to be the best solution

Comment: Android support library is not "just another library" it is an absolute essential tool for developers.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. Yet I'm not very experienced in this Android stuff :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i usually use android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar, because it's compatible with other API. The regular one will give you a lot of problems if you use it a lot in your code.